# How does HTTPS packet chunking work?

Tags: networking, proxy, http, https, packet

I am trying to bypass my ISP DPI. I found a program called [PowerTunnel](https://github.com/krlvm/PowerTunnel) hosted in GitHub that can do the trick.

When I was surfing on the GUI, I found packet chunking. I want to know, how does it work, but technically speaking.
I would appreciate a deep explanation how it works.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding

Comment: Yeah, but how does the destination server understand the chunked package?

Comment: chunking is a response thing, so the server is sending you a stream, not the other way around. as for how its understood, HTTP/1.1 compliant servers and browsers must implement the specification such that it works. a response with "chunked" set in its transfer-encodings HTTP header will be treated as chunked.